# ¿Como crear un autorun en una USB para windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, windows10, ensamblador, usb

hice un pequeño programa en `C#`, este lo tengo en una memoria usb que guarda el usuario de windows de la pc a donde se conecto el usb, pero quiero que se ejecute cada vez que lo conecte a una pc con windows pero que sea transparente para el usuario, estuve intentando con autorun.inf pero tengo entendido que este tipo de archivo ya no funciona en memoria usb y que en CD sí, pero como mi pc no tiene lector no hice la prueba así rápida, tienen alguna idea de como hacer que se ejecute automáticamente el .exe en la USB, si el autorun funciona en CD tratar de engañar a windows que la USB  es un CD o que sí se podrá hacer con un programa en `ensamblador`.

Comment: la mayoria de los antivirus y el propio windows defender bloquea este archivo por seguridad asi que esta dificil que puedas auto ejecutar desde una usb!

Comment: Aún y este hecho a nivel ensamblador?

Answer (score 3):

La funcionalidad se eliminó de Windows 7 en adelante, las computadoras con Windows hasta Vista lo tienen habilitado aunque es posible que por razones de seguridad esté deshabilitado.

Para hacerlo coloca un archivo llamado autorun.inf en la raíz de su unidad flash USB con lo siguiente:

```
[Autorun]
Open=TUAPLICACION.exe
Action=Start portable apps
Icon=diskicon.ico
```

En computadoras antiguas, el programa especificado en Open = "..." se iniciará automáticamente.

En la mayoría de las computadoras modernas (Windows 7,Windows 10), se mostrará el cuadro de diálogo "¿Qué desea hacer?" (Por razones de seguridad), pero lo que tiene en autorun.inf se mostrará como el valor predeterminado seleccionado, con Icono = "..." como icono y Acción = "..." como descripción. Si deseas iniciarlo, simplemente haz clic en el botón "Aceptar" en el cuadro de diálogo.

Probando en diferentes computadoras, ejecutando Windows XP sin SP, también en Windows XP sp 1, sp2, sp3 y en varios Vista (no estoy seguro de qué tipo, pero debería funcionar desde Vista Home Basic hasta Vista Enterprise Super-Mega Edición Premium-Extendida) y "Windows 7". También funciona en Windows 2000 (aunque la ejecución automática en Win2000 para unidades extraíbles no está habilitada en la configuración predeterminada).

Tenga en cuenta que algunas aplicaciones, además, pueden activar el diálogo de seguridad "desconocido / sin signo exacutable", como si las abriera manualmente.

Comment: Esto funciona con Windows 10?