# Aplicación Autoejecutable Desde USB (Windows 7 en adelante)

Tags: c++, windows, usb

¡Buenas!

Resulta que tengo un programa escrito en C++ (ya compilado) y me interesaría que nada mas insertar el USB en el ordenador, éste se ejecutase. He estado indagando sobre el tema y he visto que, por motivos de seguridad, la mecánica del "autorun.inf" se deshabilitó a partir de Windows 7.
Aún así lo he intentado y ni siquiera me sale un cuadro de diálogo preguntándome que deseo hacer con la unidad. Tras buscar y buscar no he encontrado nada concreto y quería saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta (posible duplicado)? [¿Como crear un autorun en una USB para windows 10?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217131/como-crear-un-autorun-en-una-usb-para-windows-10)

Comment: Lo miré pero no me funcionó. Además me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma